# Keyframe on force strength not working past frame 100

Tags: keyframes, force-fields

I am making an animation and I need to explode an object so I did a cell fracture then gave the pieces a rigid body as active and it seems to work ok. I then added a force field force. I want the object to explode only from frame 550 so I set the strength of the force to 0 from frame 1 to 549 (with keyframes) and then set the force strength to 10 at frame 550 (also keyframe), but then nothing.

If I move all the keyframes toward the beginning of the animation (before around 200 frames), and play, the explosion happens ok, but as soon as I place the keyframes at higher frame, nothing happens.

Is there a setting that limits the amount of frames for the force or the rigid body that I missed?

Comment: if my answer doesn't help, please provide your blend file

Answer (score 0):

i assume you haven't set the right rigid body frames?

Check your frames here:

[image]

Comment: This is great, that's what I was looking for. I had remove gravity but thought the start and end would be in the object properties. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please check the checkmark left to my answer if it helped you. Thank you!!